# How do I track the location of a UIView after rotation from a UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate?

Tags: ios

I'm working on a view controller transition (using a dedicated object conforming to `UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate`) where the view being presented zooms out from a subview in the presenting view. When the new view is dismissed it shrinks back into that same subview. Not too hard – but I'm stumped as to what I should do when the user rotates their device (or worse, if the window gets resized because of the new iPad multitasking) while on the presented view. How do I calculate the `CGRect` of the subview I want to shrink back in to? I'm thinking that I probably want to keep a reference to the subview in my transition object but how helpful is that when the subview is itself in a subview? (And without the whole view hierarchy I can't calculate with `convertRect:FromView:`?)

For reference the Apple Photos app in iOS9 does exactly what I'm trying to accomplish. Tap a photo from a thumbnail to see it scale up to full-screen. Rotate your device and then hit the back button and the full-screen photo shrinks back to the correct location where the thumbnail should be in the rotated view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a protocol with a method for returning the `CGRect`:

```
@protocol ZoomingTransitionFromViewDelegate <NSObject>
-(CGRect)rectForZoomingTransition;
@end
```

Make the presenting view controller adopt this protocol and pass the presenting view controller to the `UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate` during initialization. It's then the job of the presenting view controller to calculate the rect for the view.

During dismissal make sure to set the `frame` of your `toViewController` to the `frame` of the `containerView` before calling for the `rectForZoomingTransition` so that the view can resize itself for any rotation or window changes.